# How to mapping namespaced model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did that:

```
rails g model User
rails g model User/Deal
```

and make it work

```
# model/user.rb
module User
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'user_'
  end
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'users'
  end
end

# model/user/deal.rb
class User::Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

what should i do to

using

`User.create(name: 'jason')`

instead

`User::User.create(name: 'jason')`

Always use `User::User` is too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :deals, class_name: "User::Deal"
end

#app/models/user/deal.rb
class User::Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This way, you'll be able to call:

```
@user = User.create name: "Jason"
@user.deals.create title: "2 for 1"
```

Not really the answer you're looking for, so I'll delete if you want. I honestly think you're over-complicating things with a module etc.

---

**Update**

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name), your nested model will automatically look for the `module_class` table name:

> Nested classes are given table names prefixed by the singular form of the parent's table name. Enclosing modules are not considered.

```
file                  class               table_name
invoice.rb            Invoice::Lineitem   invoice_lineitems
```

However, the examples do confuse me.

If it doesn't work, you can just use `self.table_prefix` on the class:

```
#app/models/user/deal.rb
class User::Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.table_name_prefix
      "user_"
   end
end
```

Comment: Oh. Yes, that's truly what I needs. But how about `table_name_prefix` things if I did that? Should I add `self.table_name = 'user_deals'` to `User::Deal` to fix table_name?

Comment: If you wanted to keep the `deals` table for `users` only (we don't which is why I didn't include it originally), then yes you'd need to use `table_name_prefix`; I can add this to the answer if you need help with it

Comment: Thanks, Please add it.

Answer (score 0):

You've created `module User` with some purpose (I think). Maybe your task requires such 'complication'?
If in some pieces of code you want to replace `User::User` with `User`:

```
module User
  class AnotherUser
    def create
      User.create(name: 'jason')
    end
  end
end
```

Note: `class AnotherUser` is under `User` namespace! To call from outside module you'll need to use `User::AnotherUser`.